# Why after Form violation input File field are empty?

Tags: html, forms, symfony, http

Maybe this will a dumb questions, but I'll try.

For Example:

```
<form>
 First name: <input type="text" name="name">
 <br>
 Select a file: <input type="file" name="photo">
 <br>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

in this classic form I have 2 fields, name and photo. The photo can be all kind of image, the name min 4 character.

If I submit the form with a valid photo but invalid name, I'll generally redirect to the form page with the name input precompiled with the invalid name, but not with photo field precompiled.

I saw this behavior in all my useCase (generally I use Symfony).

Is this a classic http flow or other else? Can I modify this behavior?

Comment: this is a generic form, my question is not about a specify useCase. I don't think is about validation implementation.

Comment: For example, If I set a min 4 character validation for the name, and a User submit form with the string "ab" as a name.

Comment: Do you see this behaviour only in Symfony? It is definitely not default.

Comment: Yes, I ever see this behaviour in Symfony. All the image (valid or invalid) must be re-update if the form validation push some error, but all the other input not.

Comment: maybe this questions helps.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50311028/symfony-3-file-upload-in-edit-form

Comment: no, this is not the same use case. In that question, the user want not subscribe a file field during the edit mode. My way is so different: I want keep the input file type across a validation fail redirect.